# How to check if a particular object is a collection or a string?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

Specifically, I'm working with ItemProperties in the context of Outlook 2010. I want to get certain info out of the info stored in ItemProperties of a MailItem. Roughly something like this:

```
Dim folderItems As Object
Set folderItems = folder.Items
Set thisItem = folderItems(index).ItemProperties
For p = 1 To thisItem.Count
    Debug.Print thisItem.Item(p).Name & " = " & thisItem.Item(p).Value 
    '= stuff involving thisItem.Item(p) etc
Next
```

The problem is this works fine as long as the value is a straightforward String, but obviously gives an error when it comes to things like "Actions", where the value is a collection/array in themselves (have a .Count property), or simply are not a straightup string value. I'm trying to think of some way to catch those kinds of value, so as to handle them differently in the code, but I'm not able to find one.

Any help?

Comment: `TypeName()` for example?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `typeOf()`-method

Example:

```
If typeOf(thisItem.Item(p)) Is String Then
    MsgBox "String"
End If
```

To check wheter an object supports a property:

```
If IsError(thisItem.Item(p).Value Then
    MsgBox "Item doesn't support value property"
Else
    MsgBox "Item has value property"
End If
```

Comment: No, both this and TypeName() don't work. I need to handle the *value* of the item and in some of the cases, the Object doesn't support the property of Value at all. And both these methods get stuck in those instances.

Comment: Oh, I missunderstood your problem. I edited my answer